# Django MongoEngine

Tags: django, mongoengine

I've followed the guide [here](http://docs.mongoengine.org/django.html) to get MongoEngine working with Django.  Everything seems to work fine, but when trying access the admin panel, Im asked a username and password that I never created.  I've been searching around everywhere and can't find a thing.  Any ideas?

Comment: Enter `./manage.py createsuperuser` to create a new one.

Comment: Mongoengine's ORM field is actually not supported by Django yet. There are some packages out there that give admin support but for now you are forced to use supported SQL DBs to be able to manage them through Django's traditional admin template.

Comment: You should not user `Django` and `MongoDB`... It is not supported by Django and if you will look for last commit on third-party packages you will find that most of them are 1 yeat old +